# Rate of change between radius and temperature in a spherical balloon with difference of pressure proportional to the radius

Tags: fluid-statics, ideal-gas, gas

I have an spherical ballon filled with an ideal gas such that the difference of pressure between the interior $(P)$ and the exterior $(P_0)$ is proportional to the radius of the balloon:
$$P-P_0 = \xi r$$
Where $\xi$ is a constant associated to the characteristics of the balloon. I can assume that the external pressure is constant.

How can I relate a small change in the equilibrium temperature  with a small change in the radius?. In particular, I want to find $\displaystyle \frac{\Delta r}{\Delta T}$ with $\Delta r, \Delta T$ small (something like $\frac{dr}{dT}$). For example, if this ratio is constant, that means that $dr$ is proportional to $dT$. The problem here is that I don't know how to proceed. I used $PV=nRT$ assuming that the radius is dependent of the temperature and I differentiated both sides  with respect to $T$ after replacing $P$ and $V$ with the information that I have, but I just got some ugly relationship that I dont know if its correct $\Big($I found something like $\frac{dr}{dT} \propto \frac{1}{r^3+r^2}$$\Big)$. The doubt is that I assumed that the radius is dependant of the temperature, but if this isn't the case I don't know how to find the ratio. Any hints or confirmation of my results are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

well for the gas inside the balloon you can use the ideal gas equation for sure hence we have :
$$ P_{gas}\, V = nRT$$
for our system the quantity of gas is constant so let us assume that the moles of gas are constant and equal to $n_o$ and from the relation that you mentioned for the pressure we have $P_{gas} = P_{o} + \xi r $ also we know very well that $\,V = \frac{4}{3} \pi r^3$ ; this is what we all know and this yields us the following result : $$ (P_o + \xi r)\,\frac{4}{3} \pi r^3  = n_o R T$$

hence from the above equation we can see that the radius is indeed a function of temperature , if this wasn't the case then radius could have only been a constant and the ratio $ \gamma = \frac {\Delta\, r}{\Delta\,T} = 0$

let us however work the results for the previous case, well if radius is indeed a function of temperature then we can indeed use the derivative with respect to T :
$$ (3P_o r^2 + 4\xi r^3) \frac{dr}{dt} = \frac{3n_oR}{4}$$
$$(A r^2 + B r^3)\;\frac{dr}{dt}\; = \;1 \,$$
$$A = \frac{4P_o}{n_oR} \;\;\; and \;\;\; B = \frac{16\xi}{3n_oR}$$

also from our calculus courses we know that we can relate $\Delta r $ & $\Delta T$ as follows :

$$r \, - \, r_o = \frac{dr}{dT} (T-T_o)$$
$$ \Delta r =  \frac{dr}{dT} \, \Delta T$$